# Expected number of students that pass given a certain passing rule.

Tags: probability

[image]

> We're at the start of the first class of a certain subject and the students (there are only eight this year :)) are sitting at the round table pictured above. The professor comes and tells the students `Look to your class mate on your (immediate) left and (immediate) right. Out of you three, only one will pass in this subject.`

The question is

> What is the expected number of students that will pass the subject?

---

**What I've done:**

Out of three students, only one will pass; so I've taken the probability of passing for a student as $\frac{1}{3}$ and $x$ as the no. of students that pass. Followed by my calculations in the table.

$$P(x=n)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^m \cdot \frac{8!}{n!m!} \qquad ;\; m=8-n$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
n &m &(1/3)^n &(2/3)^m &8!/(m!n!) &p(x=n) &x*p(x)\\
\hline
1&7 &0.333333333&0.058527663&8&0.156073769&0.156073769\\
2&6&0.111111111&0.087791495&28 & 0.273129096 &0.546258192 \\
3 & 5 & 0.037037037 & 0.131687243 & 56 & 0.273129096 &0.819387289 \\
4 & 4 & 0.012345679 & 0.197530864 & 70 & 0.170705685 &0.68282274 \\
5 & 3 & 0.004115226 & 0.296296296 & 56 & 0.068282274 &0.34141137 \\
6 & 2 & 0.001371742 & 0.444444444 & 28 & 0.017070569 &0.102423411 \\
7 & 1 & 0.000457247 & 0.666666667 & 8 & 0.002438653 &0.017070569 \\
8 & 0 & 0.000152416 & 1 & 1 & 0.000152416 & 0.001219326\\
\hline
 &  &  &  &  & \sum(x\cdot p(x))= & 2.666666667 \\
\end{array}

$E(x)=\sum x\cdot p(x)=2.667$ = expected number of passing students.

---

Is the above method right?

Comment: The instructor’s statement is self-contradictory. Label the students $1$ through $8$ clockwise, starting with one who passes. Then neither $8$ nor $2$ can pass, and neither $7$ nor $3$ can pass, so $6$ and $4$ must pass. But this contradicts the instructor’s statement as applied to $5$.

Comment: If each student has a probability of $\dfrac13$ of passing then the expected number of passes is indeed $\dfrac83$, though I would have thought your method (a) assumes each pass is independent of the others [often not the case is there is any relative marking] and (b) is a long-winded way of doing the calculation

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I guess the statement will not work for even numbers of students.

Comment: @Henry But as per Brian M. Scott's comment the answer, though correct as per a calculation point of view, is not as per a logic view.

Comment: If @BrianM.Scott is correct then the seating arrangement is only possible for a multiple of $3$ students and exactly every third one seated around the table will pass.  In that case it is still true that each student has a probability of $\frac13$ of passing and the expected number of passes is a third of the total.